# How to implement Three.js inside Gatsby?

Tags: reactjs, three.js, gatsby, react-three-fiber

I've installed **react-three-fiber** and **three** packages. I'm following [this tutorial](https://alligator.io/react/react-with-threejs/), but I have doubts of where to put this line:

`const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");`

Also, I'm starting to receive this error:

`Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.`

My `index.js`:

```
import React, { Children, useRef, useState } from "react"

import {  Link } from "gatsby"

import { Canvas} from 'react-three-fiber'

import Layout from "../components/layout"

const IndexPage = () => {

  return(

    <Layout>

      <div>

        <h1>Hi</h1>

      </div>

      <canvas>

        <Children></Children>

      </canvas>

    </Layout>

    )

}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");

export default IndexPage
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Make sure you have installed both `three` and `react-three-fiber`.

```
npm install three react-three-fiber
```

Then in your gatsby page component just import `Canvas` from `react-three-fiber` before using it in your JSX.

```
import React from "react"
import { Canvas} from 'react-three-fiber'

import Layout from "../components/layout"

const IndexPage = () => (
  <Layout>
    <Canvas />
  </Layout>
)

export default IndexPage
```

---

Regarding `const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");` :

Although `Gatsby` is built with `React`, it doesn't require you to select a root element in order to render your app. If this sounds confusing, you should spend a little bit of time to [take a read of the Gatsby docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/tutorial/part-one/).

---

If you were to build the example from the [react-three-fiber docs](https://github.com/react-spring/react-three-fiber) in Gatsby, it would look something like this.

```
import React, { useRef, useState } from "react"
import { Canvas, useFrame } from "react-three-fiber"

const Box = props => {
  // This reference will give us direct access to the mesh so we can animate it
  const mesh = useRef()

  // Set up state for the hovered and active state
  const [hovered, setHover] = useState(false)
  const [active, setActive] = useState(false)

  // Rotate mesh every frame, this is outside of React without overhead
  useFrame(() => (mesh.current.rotation.x = mesh.current.rotation.y += 0.01))

  return (
    <mesh
      {...props}
      ref={mesh}
      scale={active ? [1.5, 1.5, 1.5] : [1, 1, 1]}
      onClick={e => setActive(!active)}
      onPointerOver={e => setHover(true)}
      onPointerOut={e => setHover(false)}
    >
      <boxBufferGeometry attach="geometry" args={[1, 1, 1]} />
      <meshStandardMaterial
        attach="material"
        color={hovered ? "hotpink" : "orange"}
      />
    </mesh>
  )
}

const IndexPage = () => (
  <Canvas>
    <ambientLight />
    <pointLight position={[10, 10, 10]} />
    <Box position={[-1.2, 0, 0]} />
    <Box position={[1.2, 0, 0]} />
  </Canvas>
)

export default IndexPage
```

[image: Edit gatsby-react-three-fibre-example]

Comment: Thanks. I also found this video which doesn't used that "rootElement". https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1rP3nNY2hTo

Comment: Unfortunately the tutorial you are following assumes a lot of existing knowledge with react and threejs. On top of that, it doesn't mention gatsby at all.